# Decode the JSON file in Java

Tags: java, jsondecoder

I'm trying to decode JSON file in JSON format using UTF-8,

But it's printing no value

```
  JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
  FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/aab6cob/Desktop/jsonFile/170902_K0_RUCd_ML_F4974.txt.insights-json");
  BufferedReader filBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(file);

  String st;
  while((st=filBufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
    byte[] tempByte = st.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
    String tempString = new String(tempByte);
    System.out.println(tempString);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't carry away with `.json` file format it is nothing but a simple text file. So you just read the file and write it in any text file using any fileStream etc.. It is quite similar to read and write a plan text file.

But if you want to load the JSON from a file into a JSON object, I advise you to read [json-simple-read-write-json-examples](https://howtodoinjava.com/json/json-simple-read-write-json-examples/)

Good luck.

Comment: need to decode while reading the file is their any reference for it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file with a specific encoding you cannot use `FileReader`. `FileReader` uses default encoding which depends on system settings. You can to use InputStreamReader's `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)` constructor for the same.
Also the two lines from your code

```
byte[] tempByte = st.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
String tempString = new String(tempByte);
```

should be removed as you are just taking a string, converting if into bytes and then again in string which makes no sense. At the end JSON file is just a text file. Read more about java's **I/O Streams** and **Character Encodings**.